# Getting error while creating bean id in spring

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring

I am getting these error while creating bean id , Im using spring :
Here is the error

**Error creating bean with name 'StockdataChart' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/web-application-config.xml]: 1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'StockdataChart' (hint: specify index and/or type arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)**

```
<s:RemoteObject id="remObj"
destination="StockdataChart" 
result="fun1(event)" 
fault="Alert.show('Error while callling remote object--'+event.fault.faultString)" />
```

here is my bean file :

```
<bean id="stockdataChart" class="com.ib.client.mts.StockdataChart">
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg> 
</bean>
<flex:remote-service  ref = "StockdataChart"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating a bean supplying the constructor-arg

```
<constructor-arg ref="dataSource"></constructor-arg>
```

You are telling Spring to instantiate the StockdataChart using the constructor which has an argument of type 'DataSource' . If you want Spring to use the default constructor, remove this . Else add a constructor as @Jigar Joshi recommends. See the reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-constructor-injection) .

Answer (score 1):

Your StockdataChart class doesnt have a constructor with dataSource ref type as parameter. If datasource is for example of type XYZ, have StockdataChart (XYZ param){} in StockdataChart  class.

Comment: where to add it??
and what will be the constructer ??
can u provide me a code??
it will be very helpful for me
thanks mate.

Comment: It should be in StockdataChart  class, please see my answer.

Comment: in stockdatachart I have 

`public StockdataChart(){
System.out.println("In historical ");`
}

still getting the error

Comment: You need to add public StockdataChart(YourDataSoruce ds){  } also right below the constructor you have.

Comment: Same like the one specified by Jigar Joshi